# Refresh button/F5 send directly to the controller(mvc) when have window.onbeforeunload in a javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to call a controller when user press Close button, so I did this:

In a javascript:

```
document.onkeydown = fkey;
var refresh = false;

function fkey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    key = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (key == 116) {
        refresh = true;
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      debugger;
      if(!refresh){
         callController();
     }
}

function callController() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/FunctionX",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: { 'refresh': refresh},
        success: function (jsonResults) {
        },
        error: function () {
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
};
```

The problem is: When I press F5 or "refresh button", and try to debug this code, the action goes directly to the Controller (FunctionX) without pass/stop in this .js

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: you have a misspelling (i.e., `debbuguer` instead of `debugger`). also where/how is `fkey()` being called

Comment: Hi @vabarbosa , you're on the true, debbuguer is a mistake when I copied to ask here, I have debugger on my code. Also, I forget to copy this line on the top: document.onkeydown = fkey; sorry

Answer (score 0):

Change your `fkey` function to this instead

```
function fkey(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.code === 'F5') {
        refresh = true;
    }
}
```

You can see a full [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/a2eo4jL0/8/) and if you watch the console you can see `callController` is not called right before the reload. You can test non-F5 reloads but clicking "Run" in jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi Eonasdan. Thank you for the answer, but still not running properly. I try to explain better: I would like to catch just the "X-close" event when you close the browser. So, this code is for ignore the F5 reloads. I read that another events, not only "X-close" event triggers window.onbeforeunload, like F5 reload. But my code still don't working, because I don't know why, the F5 event send me directly to the FunctionX at the Controller... :S